# Mississippi problem with piles

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Problem 8 on pg. 16 of Counting the art of enumerative combinatorics by George E. Martin

8. How many ways can we partition mn distinguishable objects into m piles of n objects each.

The answer is $\frac{mn!}{n!^{m}\cdot m!}$

I visualize the problem as a mississippi problem with n of each of m distinguishable letters. This results in

$\frac{mn!}{n!^{m}}$

I don't understand where the additional m! comes from. Is partition in this case a key word that requires a different counting technique? Is it because the piles them selves are indistinguishable? How do I visualize this extra constraint on the problem?

Comment: You can swap the piles around...

Comment: So AB|CD is just a permutation of CD|AB so I have to divide by the number of permutations of piles?

Comment: Yes, and you have $m$ piles...